# Getting error when doing composer Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I am on Windows. I have a Laravel Web app with composer.json as follows:

'''
{

```
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2.5",
    "bugsnag/bugsnag-laravel": "^2.18",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.10",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
    "laravel/dusk": "^5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
    "laravel/ui": "^2.0",
    "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^9.9",
    "laraveldaily/laravel-charts": "^0.1.14",
    "spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^7.19",
    "laravel/passport": "^8.4",
    "nuovo/spreadsheet-reader": "^0.5.11"
},
"require-dev": {
    "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
}
```

}
'''

Whenever I try composer Install or Composer Update it shows

> Loading composer repositories with package information

> Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

I searched online and then tried both these commands with -vvv to get all the installation messages.

Many packages were downloaded and read and written and after some time it got stuck on

> Resolving dependencies through SAT(pass #x)

It goes to 2000 or so pass and still not resolving.

I tried it after composer clear-cache but still the problem persists.

I waited it to resolve overnight but no resolution.

I am new to Web Development so please Help

Comment: please have a look at the packages already installed using composer info 
C:\folders\laravel>`composer info` _feel free to post what you see_

Comment: also, if most of the packages are loaded I would continue where i was at [laravel7 installation] https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation until `php artisan serve` to see if the server runs and work on completing the packages later as needed

Comment: @Ruperto what do you mean by continue where I was at? Also where should I run composer info command? In the project folder?

Comment: right. the composer info command needs to run in the project folder.

Comment: "where i was at" given the long described on the "composer require..." i would assume there are already many files loaded on the project folder. if you have around or more than 150MB on the project folder (using 'properties' on file explorer), that's great - i'd try command "php artisan serve"

Comment: @Ruperto I am a newbie on the whole development scene. So what do you mean by continue where I was at? if you mean create an empty project and `php artisan serve` it, That's working.

Comment: @Ruperto Output of composer info was: No dependencies installed. Try running composer install or update. Size of project folder is 2.22 mb. Also I ran compose update; It ran till`No dependencies installed. Try running composer install or update.`

Comment: i see @freeroamer90.  a reinstall would be a good option.

Comment: `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel laravel` on C:\Users\YourName\ would result in `C:\Users\YourName\laravel` or you can choose your preferred folder name

Comment: please post contents of your composer.lock file. thank you. – Ruperto

Comment: @nico haase thanks for your interest in this. i recall, for similar issues it is good to be able to see user CLI screen. it could be useful to send all commands on cmd line and all resulting errors. thank you. – Ruperto 8 mins ago